# How to generate Roslyn AST if I have only path to sln?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have path to sln file: `C:\test\test.sln` that has e.g 4 projects inside

How can I generate AST or AST per project or anything to be able to walk through those codes?

Comment: You need to create a Workspace and add the solution to it. Then you'll be able to traverse it's files getting the SyntaxTree and SemanticModel for each file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/work-with-workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MSBuildWorkspace (there's some documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/DustinCampbell/32cd69d04ea1c08a16ae5c4cd21dd3a3)) which will let you load the project. From there, the link that Carles gave will give you some hints for how to walk around.